# Only append new data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a log parser, that updates the log every 10 seconds. It's mostly functional, but when I try to update it, it just appends the whole log again, instead of just the new data.

My Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var data;
var lines;

$.ajax({
 async: false,
 type: 'GET',
 url: 'test.log',
 success: function(log) {\
    data = log;
    lines = data.split("\n");
    console.log("Received log");
 }
});

function updateLog()
{
    $.ajax({
     async: false,
     type: 'GET',
     url: 'test.log',
     success: function(log) {
        data = log.replace(data, "");
        lines = log.split("\n");

        console.log("Received log");
        }
    });

    $.each(lines, function(n, elem) 
    {
       $('#text').append('<div>' + elem + '</div>');
    });
}



$.each(lines, function(n, elem) 
{
   $('#text').append('<div>' + elem + '</div>');
});


   setInterval(function(){updateLog();}, 10000);
});
```

Example test.log content:

```
Hello
How are you?
```

But instead of it only adding potential new lines, it just copies the whole thing even though I think it shouldn't happen because of the `replace`, which is supposed to take the old `data` and change it into `''` in the new data (only leaving new lines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you save only the new part of last request to `data`, so you are actually only replacing the part of the log that was new the last time you updated the log by an empty string. Moreover, you are not using `data` but `log` (which is the full log) to compute `lines`, and are appending all the lines in `lines` to your div.

I think something like this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var processed_data = '';
    function updateLog() {
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'test.log',
            success: function(log) {
                var new_data = log.replace(processed_data, '');
                processed_data = log;
                console.log("Received log");
                var lines = new_data.split('\n');
                $.each(lines, function(n, elem) {
                   $('#text').append('<div>' + elem + '</div>');
                });
            }
        });
    }
    updateLog();
    setInterval(function(){updateLog();}, 10000);
});
```

Note that I also got rid of some of the code duplication that was in your example by just calling `updateLog()` on load instead of copying its contents.

It would also probably be more efficient to just keep track of the length of the part of the log that is already printed. Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var processed_data_length = 0;
    function updateLog() {
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'test.log',
            success: function(log) {
                var new_data = log.substring(processed_data_length, log.length);
                processed_data_length = log.length;
                console.log("Received log");

                $.each(lines, function(n, elem) {
                   $('#text').append('<div>' + elem + '</div>');
                });
            }
        });
    }
    updateLog();
    setInterval(function(){updateLog();}, 10000);
});
```

Comment: I fixed some syntax issues and defined `lines`. The first solution works well, but the second doesn't. If I append `:DD` to the log, it prints `:D` and then keeps creating new divs/lines with the left over `D`. Thank you.

Comment: Glad you liked it. I made the suggested edits. I think the second solution should now be fixed; I got the details on the indices passed to substring being inclusive / exclusive wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable, so the log variable isn't updated by the `.replace()` call. Your ajax should probably look like:

```
$.ajax({
     async: false,
     type: 'GET',
     url: 'test.log',
     success: function(log) {
        data = log.replace(data, "");
        lines = data.split("\n");

        console.log("Received log");
        }
    });
```